# Who sets the stock loan costs in U.S. markets?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, brokerage

The market "fee rate" (a.k.a. *borrow cost* ) for borrowing stock shares to sell short can run very high.  (One source for the current borrow cost is [a list published every 15 minutes by Interactive Brokers](https://ibkr.info/article/2024).)

Currently some stocks that I own are being listed with triple-digit borrow costs.  I own those stocks in a margin account with a broker where I have completed a stock lending agreement.  I can see that my shares have not been lent out.  So I have shares available to lend at the same time that short sellers are paying more than 100% annually for the shares they have borrowed to sell short.  *I would be happy to lend my shares for a small fraction of the current rate being quoted market.*

It is true that brokers take a significant cut of the "fee rate" before it is paid to any owner of shares that are lent out.  But even with that mark-up I'd be willing to undercut the market lending rate.  For example: I have un-lent shares of a stock with a fee rate of 125%.  I would be happy to lend my shares for a 20% fee.  The broker can mark that up to 40% or more and still vastly undercut the current market offer.

**How can I offer to lend my shares at net rate lower than the current market borrow cost?  And if I can't then why can't I?**